# Recommended Linear Algebra Text for Undergraduate Physics and Comp Sci

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, physics, computer-science

I'm an undergraduate freshman considering self-learning linear algebra given the free time quarantine has afforded me. I'm looking for an introductory (but comprehensive) textbook which I could use for this purpose. The course my university offers uses Lay's *Linear Algebra and Its Applications*, but I thought I'd inquire online regardless.

I expect to apply these topics in physics (quantum mechanics and general relativity) and computer science specifically, if that helps. I have seen other posters recommend *Linear Algebra* by Friedberg, Insel and Spence, but I'm not sure if that text would suit my purposes.

Comment: I recommend Linear Algebra done wrong by Sergei Treil. Since your motivation for learning linear algebra is to learn physics, this book is great. According to Treil himself and I quote  it _is not written by or for an algebraist_. which is great :)

Comment: @46_and_2 I've heard of that text! I'll check it out, thank you so much.

Comment: MIT OCW has a free "Scholar" class in Linear Algebra. A scholar class has video lectures and problem sets and exams with solutions so it is pretty well developed. https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/

Comment: If you want to study QM and GR, then learning linear algebra from Friedberg, Insel Spence is I think a great option (Chapters 1,2 are about vector spaces and linear maps, which is really the "stuff" linear algebra is studying. Chapter 3 is about relating chapter 2's concepts to matrices in order to perform calculations, chapter 4 is about determinants(not my favourite part of the text). Chapter 5 is about diagonalization, eigenvalues, eigenvectors which is absolutely essential for QM, and chapter 6 is about inner products, which is relevant/a prerequisite for both QM and GR)